# When the modifier option is true, validation object must have at least one operator - Collection 2 package - Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-collection2

I get the following error when trying to create a user :

```
Exception while invoking method 'createUser' Error: When the modifier option 
is true, validation object must have at least one operator
```

Here is how I am calling the `createUser` method :

```
Template.register.events({
  "submit #register_form": function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $form   = $("#register_form");
    var attr    = {};
    var profile = {};


    // We gather form values, selecting all named inputs
    $("input[name]", $form).each(function(idx) {
      var $input = $(this);
      var name   = $input.attr("name");


      if (name == "email" || name == "password") {
        attr[ name ] = $input.val();
      }
      else if (name != "repeat_password") {
        profile[ name ] = $input.val();
      }
    });
    attr.profile = profile;


    // Creating user account (Cf Accounts module)
    Accounts.createUser(attr, function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    }); 
  },
});
```

`attr` has the following value : 
[image]

And here is how I define the `users` schema :

```
// Setting up Simple Schema (cf module)
var profile_schema = new SimpleSchema({
  firstname: {
    type:   String,
    regEx:  /^[a-z0-9A-Z_]{3,15}$/
  },
  lastname: {
    type:   String,
    regEx:  /^[a-z0-9A-Z_]{3,15}$/
  },
  celular: {
    type:     String,
    optional: true,
  },
});


var schema = new SimpleSchema({
  emails: {
    type:   [Object],
  },
  "emails.$.address": {
    type:   String,
    regEx:  SimpleSchema.RegEx.Email
  },
  "emails.$.verified": {
    type:   Boolean
  },
  profile: {
    type:     profile_schema,
    optional: true,
  },
  createdAt: {
    type:   Date
  },
});


// Attaching Simple Schema to the users collection (Cf collection2 module)
Meteor.users.attachSchema(schema);
```

I can't find what is not right. Any suggestion is most welcomed!

Comment: try adding this to your schema
`services: {
        type: Object,
        blackbox: true
    }`

Comment: This is working. Many thanks. 
Should I always include the `services` object to my user's schema, or is this required by a given configuration of mine. I am not using any of the `accounts-#service#` plugin (ie Twitter, Facebook, Google). 

Thanks again!

Comment: Not a problem.  I turned my suggestion into an  answer since it solved your problem.  You also might be interested in https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform if you haven't seen it already.  It makes making forms in meteor really simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding my comment as an answer for visibility

You need to add the services object to your user schema as follows

```
services: { 
    type: Object,
    blackbox: true 
}
```

You need to add this even though you are not using any oAuth because Meteor adds a "service" for email login.  You should always have it.